# How does one render a component being passed in as a key of an object that is a prop?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a table component and I am looking to pass in custom react components if the user requires them. The TableCell.component looks like the following:

```
const TableCell = ({ isHeader = false, title, TitleComponent, position = defaultPosition, ...props }: TableCellProps ) => {
    if (isHeader) {
        return (
            <TableHeaderComponent position={position} {...props}>
                {TitleComponent ? TitleComponent : title}
            </TableHeaderComponent>
        );
    }
    return (
        <TableCellComponent position={position} {...props}>
            {title}
        </TableCellComponent>
    );
};
```

I am hoping to call the table as the following:

```
return <Table 
        header={{ 
            children: 'Your Table Header',
            variant: TextType.h2,
        }} 
        rows={[
            { title: 'Click Me For Function', onClick: () => alert('hiya') },
            { title: 'Center Aligned Header', position: 'center' },
            { title: 'Right Aligned Header', position: 'right' },
        ]} 
        cells={[
            [
                { TitleComponent: <CustomComponent {...props} /> },
                { title: 'Center Aligned', position: 'center' },
                { title: 'Right Aligned', position: 'right' },
            ],
        ]}
        />;
```

When I run this I can't seem to get the component that is passed in as the output. Any ideas what I am doing wrong. I see some errors around no call signatures but I don't understand why that is happening.

Cheer,

Comment: you are passing `<CustomComponent />` to title, not TitleComponent... just simply showing {title} doesnt work?

Comment: I did notice that and I fixed that locally. I will update the question. It still doesn't work

Comment: did you tried to display it like `{TitleComponent? <TitleComponent /> : title }` ?

Comment: Yes that didn't seem to work either which I thought was odd

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the best way to do this for my use case was to pass in the constructor to the Object which in this case would be `CustomComponent` and then pass another object with the props and instantiate it where I needed it.